# ng-model is getting wrong value from dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angular-ngmodel

My ng-model is updated with the first value when typing in a dropdown when some values SHARE start letters at captions.

```
 <div ng-app="dropDown" ng-controller="dropDownController">
      <select name="StateId" ng-model="selectedState" class="form-control" ng-change="selectedStateChanged()" ng-options="(states.Abbrev + ' - ' + states.Name) for states in states"></select>
      <span>{{selectedState.Name||''}}</span>
    </div>
```

**Plnkr**
http://plnkr.co/edit/pLVzK18iJxrmrL9Oiw4b?p=preview

**Scenario to test:**

1. Click on any part of the form.
2. Click Tab to focus the Dropdown.
3. Start typing 'TX'

Result:
 - 'TX - TEXAS' option is displayed on drowpdown.
 - $scope.selectedState value IS {Name:'TENNESSEE'}

Expected:

- 'TX - TEXAS' option is displayed on drowpdown.
- $scope.selectedState value should be {Name:'TEXAS'}

I'm gonna work this out by using plain javascript, in the meantime, I would like to know if theres any AngularJS solution out there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also experienced some problems with `select`. That's why it is always safer to add an empty `option`-tag!

```
<div ng-app="dropDown" ng-controller="dropDownController">
  <select name="StateId" ng-model="selectedState" class="form-control" ng-change="selectedStateChanged()" ng-options="(states.Abbrev + ' - ' + states.Name) for states in states">
    <option></option>
  </select>
  <span>{{selectedState.Name||''}}</span>
</div>
```

The solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/LfS347JM6V7Rv5S6vPkL?p=preview

---

[Angular Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) explains the problem:

> If the viewValue of ngModel does not match any of the options, then the control will automatically add an "unknown" option, which it then removes when the mismatch is resolved.
>
> Optionally, a single hard-coded  element, with the value set to an empty string, can be nested into the  element. This element will then represent the null or "not selected" option.

Comment: you saved me a lot of time. thank you. that fixed all weird issues.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using this method over a regular select tag and using `ng-repeat` on the `option` tag? I've done it that way before and it seemed to work just fine. I've only been in Angular for about 2 months so the varying ways of doing things intrigue me.

Comment: hmm I think it's basically the same, but I always use `ng-options`

Comment: @ragerory in the blue box in the doc is an explanation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select